# Codeigniter 4 default .htaccess file query

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl-certificate, canonical-link

This might sound like a stupid question to some, but I've only just noticed it while trying to implement an SSL certificate to my site.

There's a default value in the 'out of the box' .htaccess file:

```
    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Am I right in thinking this code forces the removal of the `www.` part of the canonical links on my website?

If so - is this really best practice? Is that why the `base_url` example in the `Config/App.php` is `http://example.com`?

Secondly, as I mentioned, I'm trying to add this code to the .htaccess file to implement the SSL certificate and force `https` for every URL - but it's causing an error if I use `www.` (whereas it didn't cause an error before) and my speed tests are indicating redirects galore which is slowing everything down:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction with the correct canonical link structure for the `base_url` in the `Config/App.php` file, whether I need to alter (or scrap) the first snippet of code, and how I can force `https` to work with my SSL certificate (and `www.` in my URLs).

I would much rather my URLs had the structure of `https://www.example.com` as opposed to `https://example.com`

Comment: "my speed tests are indicating redirects galore" - You need to show all the relevant directives _in-place_ so we can debug this further - the order is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking this code forces the removal of the `www.`

Yes, but only for HTTP (not HTTPS) requests, as governed by the first condition `%{HTTPS} !=on`.

If you are implementing HTTPS then you should remove the first condition and change the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string to redirect to `https://...`. But if you are wanting to redirect to `www` then you'll need to reverse the logic also:

```
# Redirect "example.com -> www.example.com"
# (In fact, redirect hostname that does not start "www.")
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Although, this particular method (as I've implied in the comment) will not necessarily work if you have other subdomains, unless you want all subdomains to have www sub-subdomains?!

Note that this is an *external* "redirect", not an *internal* "rewrite" as you'd stated in the comment.

> If so - is this really best practice?

In terms of SEO or from a technical perspective? In terms of SEO there is no difference. Using a `www` subdomain can arguably have some technical benefits (isolating cookies and staging sites, etc.) - although this is mostly a matter of opinion and depends on your environment. It is really up to you. For some domain names, using a `www` subdomain just *looks* cumbersome.

But what is important is that you choose one or the other and redirect to the canonical URL in order to avoid *potential* duplicate content issues.

Using the domain apex (ie. no www subdomain) is simply CodeIgniters *default*.

> force https for every URL - but it's causing an error if I use `www.`

To clarify, the SSL cert you implement must include both the domain apex, ie. `exmaple.com` and the www subdomain, ie. `www.example.com`. Otherwise, you will naturally get browser security warnings when requesting the "other" (non-SSL) hostname.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

This code is generally OK to force HTTP to HTTPS (providing the SSL cert is installed on your application server, ie. you're not using a front-end SSL proxy or non-standard implementation). However, the order you put this rule in relation to the rule above will depend on whether you intend to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) or not.

If you are intending to implement HSTS then you will *need* to redirect to HTTPS on the same host *first*, before the redirect to www. This will result in an unavoidable double redirect when requesting the non-canonical `http://example.com/` (but that is not "bad").

For example:

```
# 1. Redirect to HTTPS on the same host
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# 2. Redirect to non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If, however, you are not intending to implement HSTS then you can reverse the two rules above and get at most one redirect for any non-canonical URL request.

You need to update the CodeIgniter `base_url` to match your preference of www or not.

Comment: [MrWhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369434/mrwhite) Thank you for your answer - it gave me more guidance than I could ever have hoped for! I've copied the code you provided, and played around with the order. It does what it's intended to do - it redirects to `https://www.` - but I get a load error for having `too many redirects`

Comment: What is reporting this "too many redirects" _error_? And what exactly are the redirects you are seeing? (What URL is being requested?)

Comment: Got it sorted thanks! Your solution did work perfectly... I had a Cloudfare CDN activated and it’s firewall was messing things up.